# A smarter way to do this JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code, where the user can click certain checkboxes, and based on their input, they are provided an output with various answers.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so I'm just trying to dig in to some cases in order to learn. I'm pretty convinced that there is a smarter way to do this JS code, but I'm not sure how.

I do not wish for you to necessarily perform the correct way to code, but just tell me about the direction in which I should go to do this "right".

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .hide {
      display: none; //add this property
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="decider hide">
    <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Hvilken bolig bor du i?</p>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="egetHus" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Eget hus/rækkehus </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="lejetHus" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Lejet hus/rækkehus</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="lejlighed" type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" />
        Ejer-/lejet lejlighed</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="fritidshus" type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1" />
        Fritidshus</label>
    <br />

    <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Har du børn?</p>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="hjemmeboendeBoern" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Hjemmeboende børn</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="udeboendeBoern" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Udeboende børn</label>
    <br />

    <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Hvilket transportmidler har du?</p>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="bil" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Bil</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="motorcykel" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Motorcykel</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="knallert" type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" />
        Knallert</label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="cykel" type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1" />
        Cykel</label>
    <br />

    <span class="select"> 
        <input type="button" id="send-decide" alt="submit" value="select" />
    </span> 
  </div>

  <!-- VISIBLE IF CHECKED -->
  <div class="egetHus">
    <p>this is first box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="lejetHus">
    <p>this is second box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="lejlighed">
    <p>this is third box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="fritidshus">
    <p>this is fourth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="hjemmeboendeBoern">
    <p>this is fifth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="udeboendeBoern">
    <p>this is sixth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bil">
    <p>this is sixth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="motorcykel">
    <p>this is sixth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="knallert">
    <p>this is sixth box</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cykel">
    <p>this is sixth box</p>
  </div>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.decider').removeClass('hide');
      $('.egetHus,.lejetHus,.lejlighed,.fritidshus,.hjemmeboendeBoern,.udeboendeBoern,.bil,.motorcykel,.knallert,.cykel').addClass('hide'); //add hide to both the class


      $("#send-decide").click(function() {
        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {

          $('.decider ').addClass('hide');
          if ($('#egetHus').is(':checked')) {
            $('.egetHus').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#lejetHus').is(':checked')) {
            $('.lejetHus').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#lejlighed').is(':checked')) {
            $('.lejlighed').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#fritidshus').is(':checked')) {
            $('.fritidshus').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#hjemmeboendeBoern').is(':checked')) {
            $('.hjemmeboendeBoern').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#udeboendeBoern').is(':checked')) {
            $('.udeboendeBoern').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#bil').is(':checked')) {
            $('.bil').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#motorcykel').is(':checked')) {
            $('.motorcykel').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#knallert').is(':checked')) {
            $('.knallert').removeClass('hide');
          }
          if ($('#cykel').is(':checked')) {
            $('.cykel').removeClass('hide');
          }
        } else
          alert('select a checkbox');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the result supposed to be because it doesn't seem to be giving accurate results?

Comment: It would probably be easier to work out if you didn't have HTML that stated five different checkboxes were all the sixth box.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all `if else` statement with the following code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, el) {
    $('.' + el.id).removeClass('hide')
});
```

this will work, because every checkbox's id and corresponding p's class are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I made this somewhat clean and simple. Try out and comment if the o/p is not correct.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [
    'egetHus',
    'lejetHus',
    'lejlighed',
    'fritidshus',
    'hjemmeboendeBoern',
    'udeboendeBoern',
    'bil',
    'motorcykel',
    'knallert',
    'cykel'
  ];
  
  $('.decider').removeClass('hide');
  
  $.each(arr, function(key, elem) {
    $('.' + elem).addClass('hide'); //add hide to both the class
  });

  $("#send-decide").click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
      $('.decider ').addClass('hide');
      $.each(arr, function(key, elem) {
        if ($('#' + elem).prop('checked') === true) {
          $('.' + elem).removeClass('hide');
        }
      });
    } else
      alert('select a checkbox');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none; //add this property
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="decider hide">
  <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Hvilken bolig bor du i?</p>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="egetHus" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Eget hus/rækkehus </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="lejetHus" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Lejet hus/rækkehus</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="lejlighed" type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" />
        Ejer-/lejet lejlighed</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="fritidshus" type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1" />
        Fritidshus</label>
  <br />

  <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Har du børn?</p>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="hjemmeboendeBoern" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Hjemmeboende børn</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="udeboendeBoern" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Udeboende børn</label>
  <br />

  <p style="font-size:18px;color:#000;">Hvilket transportmidler har du?</p>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="bil" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
        Bil</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="motorcykel" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
        Motorcykel</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="knallert" type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" />
        Knallert</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input id="cykel" type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1" />
        Cykel</label>
  <br />

  <span class="select"> 
        <input type="button" id="send-decide" alt="submit" value="select" />
      </span> </div>

<!-- VISIBLE IF CHECKED -->
<div class="egetHus">
  <p>this is first box</p>
</div>

<div class="lejetHus">
  <p>this is second box</p>
</div>

<div class="lejlighed">
  <p>this is third box</p>
</div>

<div class="fritidshus">
  <p>this is fourth box</p>
</div>

<div class="hjemmeboendeBoern">
  <p>this is fifth box</p>
</div>

<div class="udeboendeBoern">
  <p>this is sixth box</p>
</div>

<div class="bil">
  <p>this is sixth box</p>
</div>

<div class="motorcykel">
  <p>this is sixth box</p>
</div>

<div class="knallert">
  <p>this is sixth box</p>
</div>

<div class="cykel">
  <p>this is sixth box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer given by @RubenVardanyan works better if you have only checkboxes. You should give that a try.